# How to send file to client without saving it immadiately

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

I need to send a file from my backend application to a client using rest api. Right now this code works pretty fine

```
@GET
@Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")
public Response getFile(){
 StreamingOutput fileStream = service.doSomeLogic();

 return Response.ok(fileStream, "application/vnd.ms-excel").header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=someFile.xls").build();
}
```

My problem is that when I enter given endpoint, the file is downloaded immediately, without 'menu' to chose where to save, or how to name the file. Before I've used Spring and returned `Response byte[]` or something like that, and it worked as I need now - without saving immediately.

I've tried sending back `byte[]`, but the effect was the same.

Comment: What browser did you test this on?

Comment: Thats a browser feature

Comment: Right now I use opera, in previous project (with spring) I've used chrome. So it might be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Settings-> Advance
This is an example for settings in Chrome if you disable this it will ask for the location else will download directly to the default location.

below is the example for Mozilla

[image]